# Time complexity of the includes method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, time-complexity

I have an array that contains some hash values of certain strings,
I don't want duplicate values in my array so I use `if` logic like this:

```js
if(!arrayOfHash.includes(hash_value)){
  arrayOfHash.push(hash_value); 
}
```

I want to know the complexity of the `includes` method in JavaScript.
Is it a **linear search** function or is it a modified search function?

Comment: If you write something like this it can be O(n) just one for loop is enough

Comment: ya  if it is implemented as a linear search , can i check the internal working of includes() function anywhere ...?

Comment: Also you can check https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: You can do `arrayOfHash = Array.from(new Set(hash_values))` to remove duplicates in O(n)

Comment: thanks bro ..so i  have to use hashMap (dictionary) to reduce my complexity o(1 ) time ...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Spec describes this function as linear search. [Array.prototype.includes](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.includes)

> 1. Let O be ? ToObject(this value).
> 2. Let len be ? ToLength(? Get(O, "length")).
> 3. If len is 0, return false.
> 4. Let n be ? ToInteger(fromIndex). (If fromIndex is undefined, this step produces the value 0.)
> 5. If n ≥ 0, then   Let k be n.
> 6. Else n < 0, Let k be len + n. If k < 0, let k be 0.
> 7. **Repeat, while k < len**  ... **Increase k by 1.**

Which is quite a reasonable choice in general case (list is not sorted, list is not uniform, you do not maintain additional datastructures along with the list itself).

Comment: That line 7 you put in bold implies it is a loop **"Repeat, while k < len ... Increase k by 1."**. And it states above "The optional second argument fromIndex defaults to +0 (i.e. the whole array is searched)" so I think that means O(n). How are you getting O(1)?

Comment: @garrettmac Linear search is `O(n)` right. I am not saying it is `O(1)`. What makes you think so, BTW?

Comment: @garrettmac have you, by accident, looked at the second answer here? O(n), as I am sure you are aware, is linear time, and O(1) is constant time, and nowhere does Yury say that the search has O(1) time complexity...

Comment: Y’all are 100% right, I feel silly now. Thank you for correcting me.

Answer (score 1):

as my list is not sorted so i have create a dictionary and put values into it after checking if value present in it or not . Here in this dictionary my value and key are same .

```
var   arrayOfHashMap = {};/*is a dictionary,arrayOfValue is a list*/
    if(arrayOfHashMap[hash_value] !=hash_value){
                               arrayOfValue.push(hash_value); 
                               arrayOfHashMap[hash_value]=hash_value;
                        }
```

in this case I search values in **o(1)** time and put them in **arrayOfValue**